# Win Phone System.Windows.Controls.Control not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-controls

I'm developing a universal windows 8.1 app, though I'm primarily working on the windows phone version.

System.Controls.control should work for windows phone, but whenever I add System.Windows.Controls.dll to my Win Phone 8.1 references, my project won't compile and it says:

```
Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.Control in module System.Windows.dll
```

This happens whether or not i actually say "using system.win.." etc, it happens as soon as I add it to my project references. This dll is from my programfiles(x86)/microsoftsdks/silverlight directory.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use Silverlight controls in a WinRT app. That won't work. New UI controls are a part of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.

Find the list of controls which are in that namespace [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.aspx). Also, please read [more about the two different XAML models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/15/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-choose-your-windows-phone-xaml-app-model.aspx) available in Windows Phone 8.1.